# Rebase my changes on top of another branch updates in Sublime Merge

Tags: git, sublimemerge

I cloned a Git repo/branch (`origin/master`). I made my changes and committed on another branch (`mine`) and I set another remote for it (`office/mine`). I did three commits actually.

Now there are updates on `origin/master` that I need to incorporate. I guess what I need is to rebase my changes on top of latest `origin/master`, but I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

I'm using Sublime Merge and I can't see that option or I'm not looking on the right menus.

Comment: Go to your terminal and use the `git rebase` command. You don't need Sublime Merge for that.

Comment: I'm scared of having to handle conflicts on the terminal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to replicate the command `git rebase origin/master mine` in Sublime Merge:

- Check out the branch you want to rebase (`mine`).
- In the "Commits" view (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> by default), right-click on the latest commit of the branch you want to rebase *onto* (`origin/master`).
- Choose "Rebase mine onto origin/master".

Comment: It looks like my commits are re-created on top of latest `origin/master`, which makes sence. Should I push this `mine` to `office/mine`?

Comment: That's the nature of a rebase. I don't know if you want to push this to office/mine. If you want to sync the "office" repository to the current state, then probably yes.

Comment: Following these instructions I reached a diverged state. One additional merge then seem to clean things.